# Can I receive data on the Arduino by sending data to /dev/ttyACM0?

Tags: serial, usb

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi connected to an Arduino.
When I execute

```
echo 'Hello' > /dev/ttyACM0
```

, the Arduino receives the data, as indicated by its LED. How can I read the data on the Arduino and process it?

Comment: start with a simple google search "arduino serial data read" or any similar combination, you will find a myriad of written tutorials and videos. If you've followed such tutorials, edit your question and show us which one (with a link), post your code and tell us a little more about what you've done and what's exactly not working. Then you might get a real answer to this question, although if you do that (above) you will arrive at the answer all on your own, I'm sure of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Serial.read() there are plenty of examples that come with the Arduino IDE, just make sure the baud rates on the Raspberry Pi and Arduino match.